# How to add points dynamically like this "..." to indicates that there are more pagination buttons

Tags: reactjs, pagination

**I'm trying to add like this "..." in between my pagination buttons if they are more than five buttons, can any one please help me with this. this is my pagination's code:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const Pagination = ({productsPerPage, totalPosts, paginate}) => {
const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0)
const PageNumbers =[]

const int = Math.ceil(totalPosts / productsPerPage)
    if (int === 1 ) return null 
    for (let i = 1; i<= int; i++) {
        PageNumbers.push(i) 
    }


    return (
        <nav className="">
            <ul className="pagination">
                 {PageNumbers.includes(currentPage - 1) && 
                <a className="page-link" href="!#" onClick={() => 
                    { setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1);  
                    paginate(currentPage - 1); }}> Previous
                 </a>}

                    {PageNumbers.map(number=> (
                        <li key={number} className={number === currentPage ? 'page-item' : 'page-item '}>
                            <a onClick={ ()=> paginate(number)} href="!#" className="page-link active">
                                {number} 
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    ))}

                 {PageNumbers.includes(currentPage + 1) && 
                <a className="page-link" href="!#" onClick={() => 
                    {setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1); 
                    paginate(currentPage + 1); }}> Next 
                </a>}
            </ul>
        </nav>
    )
}

export default Pagination
```

Comment: So what is the desired output? 1....5 ?

Comment: the desired output like this: < 1,2 ... 55 ... 90,91 >

Comment: What determines that it should show "55" rather than any other number?

Comment: Yes, you're right or any other number, not just specific 55

Answer (score 2):

Replace your return function with below code:

```
return (
     <nav className="">
       <ul className="pagination">      
        {PageNumbers.map(number => (          
            (number < 3 || (number > currentPage-2 && number < currentPage+2) || 
               number > PageNumbers.length - 2 )  ?
           <li
              key={number}
              className={number === currentPage ? "page-item" : "page-item "}
           >
             <a
               onClick={() => paginate(number)}
               href="!#"
               className={"page-link " + number ===currentPage ?'active':''}
             >
                {number}
             </a>
          </li>
          :
          PageNumbers.length>5 && number < 4 ? '...'
          : 
          number < PageNumbers.length && number == currentPage+2 ? '...'
          :null

      ))}
    </ul>
   </nav>
);
```

Above code shows first two page number, last two page number and current page number with previous page number and next page number, rest page number's will be dot dot.

Comment: Ooh thanks it's working nicely, but do you know to add next and previous buttons to it?

Comment: yes, you can add next and previous buttons, For buttons refer same code in your question, just make sure both buttons are present in outside the map function and inside the <ul>.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But is there any way to make them both appeared, because when I click on next to the last one the prev button disappeared. Can you please fix this to make them appeared